# how to upload, download file from tomcat server with username,password in swing

Tags: java, http, tomcat

I want to make a program in swing which connect to tomcat server running locally. with username,password authentication, then user able to upload file in server directory. ie.http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles.  from user defined file path , and same as download to the local directory.

Comment: Have you tried the HttpClient tutorial - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html?

Comment: The above code got java.net.* package more or less correct. The only thing I've noticed urlconnection.setDoOutput(), which is used for POST requests. Also you should always check urlconnection.getResponseCode() before reading server response.

Comment: You need more detail as to what problems you are encountering, how you're handling it on the server end, etc. Lots of unknowns here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:
Download:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    try {
        con.addRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Basic " + encode64(username + ":" + password));
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            try {
                byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                for (int n = in.read(buf); n > 0; n = in.read(buf)) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }
```

Upload:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/uploadfiles");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)uploadUrl.openConnection();
    try {
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.addRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Basic " + encode64(username + ":" + password));
        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            try {
                byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
                for (int n = in.read(buffer); n > 0; n = in.read(buffer)) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
        int code = con.getResponseCode();
        if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String msg = con.getResponseMessage();
            throw new IOException("HTTP Error " + code + ": " + msg);
        }
    } finally {
        con.disconnect();
    }
```

Now, on the server side, you will need to distinguish between GET and POST requests and handle them accordingly. You will need a library to handle uploads, such as apache [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Oh, and on the client side, you will need a library that does Base64 encoding such as apache [commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)