# Remotely deploy war file to Tomcat using java code

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a `RESTful` web service to a web server with `Tomcat 8` from `Eclipse`.

I tried using *`HttpClient`* using the code from the second answer of this post: [Tomcat: remote programmatic deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498577/tomcat-remote-programmatic-deploy) but I get this exception
`java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error.`

I also tried with *`HttpURLConnection`* using the code from the first answer of this post: [how to upload, download file from tomcat server with username,password in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608428/how-to-upload-download-file-from-tomcat-server-with-username-password-in-swing) but I also get an error.

What could be the reason? Is there another way? Thank you.

Comment: Is the Tomcat install on the same machine as Eclipse?

Comment: No, it is in a different machine. I can use Tomcat Manager to deploy the web service but I would like to do it from java code with http PUT request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... it is in a different machine. I can use Tomcat Manager to deploy the web service but I would like to do it from java code with http PUT request.

In order for that to be possible, the deployment folder would need to be accessible from the HTTP server or web application.  That's generally a bad idea for security reasons.

You can still do it programmatically with Java (or other language) by calling any of the many utilities for file transfers:  ftp, scp, networked file system, etc.

Note that after you have copied the artifact (eg war file) to the Tomcat host, you can then tell Tomcat to deploy it remotely via the deployment manager url.  From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_a_Directory_or_WAR_by_URL):

> In this example the web application located in the directory /path/to/foo on the Tomcat server is deployed as the web application context named /footoo.
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/footoo&war=file:/path/to/foo
> ```
>
> In this example the ".war" file /path/to/bar.war on the Tomcat server is deployed as the web application context named /bar. Notice that there is no path parameter so the context path defaults to the name of the web application archive file without the ".war" extension.
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?war=jar:file:/path/to/bar.war!/
> ```

Your code could copy the artifact via scp (or whatever) and if successful call the manager URL with appropriate arguments.  A two step process in a single code run.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answer! It works! I used **sftp** to upload the file in the **webapps** folder of Tomcat server. Since in **server.xml autodeploy=true**, I didn't have to do HTTP PUT request. Here is my code, based on this [link](http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-uploading-file-to-sftp-server/):

```
String SFTPHOST = "1.2.3.4";
int SFTPPORT = 22;
String SFTPUSER = "root";
String SFTPPASS = "password";
String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/home/username/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/webapps/";
Session session = null;
Channel channel = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd("..");
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File("path/to/war");
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
} catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

}
```